# Tengo texto PHP dentro de HTML, que además está dentro de una variable de PHP, pero no lo ejecuta como php

Tags: php, html

Lo primero decir que soy principiante en este tema, os comento.

El problema es que tengo código PHP dentro de HTML, y a la vez este texto HTML está dentro de una variable de PHP.

Cuando intento ver la página en el servidor, no ejecuta la parte de PHP que está dentro de HTML.

He mirado en varios foros, y probado muchas cosas.... pero estoy muy perdido.

```
if($totalResult > 0) {
        /*while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {*/
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            
            $searchResultHTML .= '
                     <div class="col-sm-4">
                    
                        <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="single-products">
                                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                    <img src="imagenes/productos/<?php echo $row["Foto1"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row["Nombre"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $row["Nombre"]; ?>"/>
                                <?php if ($row["Reservado"] !="") {echo"<img class="pricing" src="imagenes/web/reservado.png" title="Reservado-'.$row["Nombre"].'" alt="Reservado-'.$row["Nombre"].'"/>"; }?>
                                <?php if ($row["Vendido"] !="") {echo"<img class="pricing" src="imagenes/web/vendido.png" title="Vendido-'.$row["Nombre"].'" alt="Vendido-'.$row["Nombre"].'"/>"; }?>
                                    <h2><?php echo $row["Precio"]." €"; ?></h2>
                                    <p><?php
                                        $texto = $row["Nombre"];
                                        $texto = substr($texto, 0, 25);
                                        echo $texto; //esto dara solo "texto de"


                                    ?></p>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <?php $id_detalle = $row["IdProducto"];
                                      $fotoface = $row["Foto1"];
                                ?>
                                <a href="producto_automoviles_joma.php?id_detalle=<?php echo $id_detalle ?>&fotoface=<?php echo $fotoface ?>">
                                <div class="product-overlay">
                                    <div class="overlay-content">
                                        <h2><?php echo $row["Nombre"]; ?></h2>
                                        <p><?php echo $row["Kilometros"]; ?>  Km</p>
                                        <p>Año:  <?php echo $row["Ano"]; ?></p>
                                        <p>Caballos: <?php echo $row["Caballos"]; ?>  Cv</p>
                                        <p><?php echo $row["Combustible"]; ?></p>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="limpia"> </div>
                    </div>
                    ';
            
                    //Final del bucle
            ;
            
        }
    } else {
        $searchResultHTML = '<h3>No se ha encontrado ningún producto..</h3>';
    }
    return $searchResultHTML;   
    
}
```

Resultado en la consola del navegador Chrome:

[image: Resultado en la consola del navegador Chrome]

Comment: Cuando llegues a la apertura `<img src="imagenes/productos/` agrega un '. $codigo_php. ' si cierras

Comment: y quita los `echo`

Comment: Si vas a ejecutar PHP dentro de HTML, solo hazlo como PHP normal, no declarado como HTML primeramente...

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Todavía me quedo encallado en los <>php if, no sé cómo poner esos condicionales. Ni siquiera sé si es el lugar correcto.

Comment: Te recomendaria que usaras un archivo exclusivamente para mostrar datos y otro para la logica del programa/aplicacion. Si ya tienes un conocimiento medio en php te recomendaria que aprendieras algun framework que use plantillas (no estoy seguro de si todos los frameworks usan) Yo aprendi a usar laravel y la verdad que es muy comodo en ese sentido

Answer (score 1):

Encontrar un error en una mezcla de código PHP/HTML es tarea harto difícil y nadie te librará de que termines con un fuerte dolor de cabeza y que pierdas una parte importante de tu vista. Sin broma, esa mezcla debería estar prohibida, al menos por motivos de salud, pero en fin.

Para casos como estos yo suelo hacer lo siguiente:

1. Tratar de mantenerme lo más posible dentro de un solo bloque, en este caso PHP.
2. Concatenar todo en una sola variable. **Rodeando esa variable de comillas dobles**.

   - Esto tiene dos ventajas nada despreciables:

     a. Podrás usar variables dentro de las comillas dobles sin problemas

     b. Podrás prescindir de las comillas para referirte a las claves de array, como podrás ver que hago al leer los valores de `$row`
   - Y tiene una desventaja:

     **Tendrás que escapar con `\` las comillas de los elementos HTML** como `class=\"laClase\"`. Prefiero esto mil veces a el horrible espaghetti de la mezcla de bloques.

Mira el código aplicando lo antes dicho:

```
/*
  Supongo que la variable está definida antes...
  sea como sea, la cambiamos por algo más breve ($HTML)
  NO hace falta exagerar con los nombres de variable en estos casos 
*/
$HTML="";
if($totalResult > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $HTML .= "
                     <div class=\"col-sm-4\">
                        <div class=\"product-image-wrapper\">
                            <div class=\"single-products\">
                                <div class=\"productinfo text-center\">
                                    <img src=\"imagenes/productos/$row[Foto1]\" alt=\"$row[Nombre]\" title=\"$row[Nombre]\"/>";
                                    
                                    if ($row["Reservado"] !="") {
                                      $HTML.="<img class=\"pricing\" src=\"imagenes/web/reservado.png\" title=\"Reservado-$row[Nombre]\" alt=\"Reservado-$row[Nombre]\"/>";
                                    }
                                    if ($row["Vendido"] !="") {
                                      $HTML.="<img class=\"pricing\" src=\"imagenes/web/vendido.png\" title=\"Vendido-$row[Nombre]\" alt=\"Vendido-$row[Nombre]\"/>";
                                      $texto=substr($row['Nombre'], 0, 25);
                                    $HTML.="<h2>$row[Precio] €</h2>
                                            <p>                                               
                                              $texto
                                            </p>
                                </div>
                                <a href=\"producto_automoviles_joma.php?id_detalle=$row[IdProducto]&fotoface=$row[Foto1]\">
                                <div class=\"product-overlay\">
                                    <div class=\"overlay-content\">
                                        <h2>$row[Nombre]></h2>
                                        <p>$row[Kilometros]  Km</p>
                                        <p>Año:  $row[Ano]</p>
                                        <p>Caballos: $row[Caballos] Cv</p>
                                        <p>$row[Combustible]></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=\"limpia\"> </div>
                    </div>";            
        }
    } else {
        $HTML = '<h3>No se ha encontrado ningún producto..</h3>';
    }
    return $HTML;   
    
}
```

**NÓTESE** que he nombrado la variable de concatenación `$HTML` solamente. Para algo utilitario no hace falta darle un nombre tannn descriptivo y largo como `$searchResultHTML`, aunque eso es cuestión de gustos.

En cuanto al código, espero no haberme equivocado en algo, si así ha sido, entendidos los puntos que dije al principio, el error será fácil de encontrar analizando lo que imprima `$HTML`. De hecho, trabajando así, te das cuenta rápidamente de algo que suena raro: Tú estás abriendo un anchor tag con contenido en pantalla multibloque, que incluye un `div`, un `h2` y un elemento `p`  ¿?  Eso es muy extraño, pero bueno ...

Comment: Buena respuesta; solo hay un detalle: Se recomienda usar la [sintaxis compleja](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) para incluir elementos de arreglo en una cadena. Ejemplo: `echo "Texto {$arreglo['indice']} más texto";`

Comment: Gracias @Triby. No obstante, mi propuesta aquí es precisamente evitar tantos `echo`, recogiendo todo en una variable final (`$HTML`) que será retornada, por eso no he usado la sintaxis compleja, porque creo que en este escenario concreto solamente cargaría más el código. Debo decir que es una apreciación mía...

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a todos. En especial a A. Cedano. Después de 5 días dejándome los sesos... (y la vista) con tu respuesta a quedado perfecto. Y he tardado 5 min... Si te hubiera conocido antes.......  : ) . Lo dicho muchísimas gracias.